# Error during Starting Android Activity

Tags: android, eclipse

I have written the following code to read and display the html files in my android application. But The activity is not starting. Its showing "unfortunately app stopped working". The java class is as follows:

```
package com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class htmlViewer extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.htmlviewer);
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);   

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fileContent);

        File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    //    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

       //     String newloc = extras.getString("loc");






        File file = new File(dir,"test.html");


        if(file.exists())  
        {

            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {

            }
           // tv.setText(text);
            String html = text.toString();
             String mimeType = "text/html";
             String encoding = "UTF-8";
            wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("",html, mimeType, encoding, "");

        }
        else
        {
        tv.setText("Sorry file doesn't exist!!");
        }

     } 

}
```

And the logcat is as follows:

```
08-27 21:21:56.916: I/ActivityManager(286): START u0 {cmp=com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1/.htmlViewer (has extras)} from pid 1073
08-27 21:21:56.936: W/WindowManager(286): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21015
08-27 21:21:57.367: D/AndroidRuntime(1073): Shutting down VM
08-27 21:21:57.367: W/dalvikvm(1073): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1/com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1.htmlViewer}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073):     at com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1.htmlViewer.onCreate(htmlViewer.java:58)
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-27 21:21:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1073):     ... 11 more
08-27 21:21:57.677: W/ActivityManager(286):   Force finishing activity com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1/.htmlViewer
08-27 21:21:57.687: W/ActivityManager(286):   Force finishing activity com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1/.FileManager
08-27 21:21:58.196: W/ActivityManager(286): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4104a8e0 u0 com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1/.htmlViewer}
08-27 21:21:58.387: I/Choreographer(286): Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-27 21:21:58.437: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-27 21:22:00.436: I/Choreographer(402): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-27 21:22:01.666: I/Process(1073): Sending signal. PID: 1073 SIG: 9
08-27 21:22:01.737: I/ActivityManager(286): Process com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1 (pid 1073) has died.
08-27 21:22:01.737: W/InputDispatcher(286): channel '40f4db50 com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1/com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1.Home (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
08-27 21:22:01.756: E/InputDispatcher(286): channel '40f4db50 com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1/com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1.Home (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-27 21:22:01.756: W/InputDispatcher(286): channel '40f70d70 com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1/com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1.FileManager (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
08-27 21:22:01.756: E/InputDispatcher(286): channel '40f70d70 com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1/com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1.FileManager (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-27 21:22:01.796: I/WindowState(286): WIN DEATH: Window{40f4db50 u0 com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1/com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1.Home}
08-27 21:22:01.796: W/InputDispatcher(286): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '40f4db50 com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1/com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1.Home (server)'
08-27 21:22:01.806: I/WindowState(286): WIN DEATH: Window{40f70d70 u0 com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1/com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1.FileManager}
08-27 21:22:01.806: W/InputDispatcher(286): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '40f70d70 com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1/com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1.FileManager (server)'
08-27 21:22:01.856: D/dalvikvm(1090): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
08-27 21:22:01.896: I/ActivityManager(286): Start proc com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1 for activity com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1/.Home: pid=1090 uid=10046 gids={50046, 3003, 1028}
08-27 21:22:01.976: I/dalvikvm(286): Jit: resizing JitTable from 8192 to 16384
08-27 21:22:02.146: I/Choreographer(286): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-27 21:22:02.286: I/Choreographer(286): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-27 21:22:02.326: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-27 21:22:02.587: I/Choreographer(286): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-27 21:22:02.706: E/Trace(1090): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-27 21:22:02.787: I/Choreographer(286): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-27 21:22:03.556: D/dalvikvm(1090): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 69K, 8% free 2498K/2688K, paused 50ms, total 52ms
08-27 21:22:03.576: I/dalvikvm-heap(1090): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.141MB for 614416-byte allocation
08-27 21:22:03.698: D/dalvikvm(1090): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 3096K/3292K, paused 120ms, total 120ms
08-27 21:22:03.806: D/dalvikvm(1090): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3131K/3292K, paused 10ms+6ms, total 109ms
08-27 21:22:04.126: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-27 21:22:04.207: W/InputMethodManagerService(286): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1073 uid 10046
08-27 21:22:04.256: I/Choreographer(1090): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-27 21:22:04.286: D/gralloc_goldfish(1090): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-27 21:22:04.496: I/ActivityManager(286): Displayed com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1/.Home: +2s674ms (total +7s519ms)
08-27 21:22:31.388: D/ExchangeService(633): Received deviceId from Email app: null
08-27 21:22:31.388: D/ExchangeService(633): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
08-27 21:22:36.507: D/ExchangeService(633): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
08-27 21:22:36.507: D/ExchangeService(633): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
08-27 21:22:36.527: W/ActivityManager(286): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
08-27 21:22:36.536: D/ExchangeService(633): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
08-27 21:22:36.547: D/ExchangeService(633): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
08-27 21:22:36.566: W/ActivityManager(286): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d26980 that was originally bound here
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d26980 that was originally bound here
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-27 21:22:36.586: E/ActivityThread(633):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633): null
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d26980 that was originally bound here
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-27 21:22:36.686: E/StrictMode(633):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-27 21:22:36.696: W/ActivityManager(286): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@41019d50
08-27 21:22:36.717: E/ActivityThread(633): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d26338 that was originally bound here
08-27 21:22:36.717: E/ActivityThread(633): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d26338 that was originally bound here
08-27 21:22:36.717: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
08-27 21:22:36.717: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
08-27 21:22:36.717: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
08-27 21:22:36.717: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
08-27 21:22:36.717: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
08-27 21:22:36.717: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
08-27 21:22:36.717: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
08-27 21:22:36.717: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
08-27 21:22:36.717: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
08-27 21:22:36.717: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
08-27 21:22:36.717: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
08-27 21:22:36.717: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-27 21:22:36.717: E/ActivityThread(633):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-27 21:22:36.717: E/ActivityThread(633):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-27 21:22:36.717: E/ActivityThread(633):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-27 21:22:36.717: E/ActivityThread(633):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-27 21:22:36.827: E/StrictMode(633): null
08-27 21:22:36.827: E/StrictMode(633): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d26338 that was originally bound here
08-27 21:22:36.827: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
08-27 21:22:36.827: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
08-27 21:22:36.827: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
08-27 21:22:36.827: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
08-27 21:22:36.827: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
08-27 21:22:36.827: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
08-27 21:22:36.827: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
08-27 21:22:36.827: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
08-27 21:22:36.827: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
08-27 21:22:36.827: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
08-27 21:22:36.827: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
08-27 21:22:36.827: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-27 21:22:36.827: E/StrictMode(633):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-27 21:22:36.827: E/StrictMode(633):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-27 21:22:36.827: E/StrictMode(633):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-27 21:22:36.827: E/StrictMode(633):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-27 21:22:36.846: W/ActivityManager(286): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40f70588
08-27 21:22:36.846: D/dalvikvm(633): GC_CONCURRENT freed 463K, 20% free 2482K/3072K, paused 77ms+79ms, total 252ms
08-27 21:23:21.586: D/ExchangeService(633): Received deviceId from Email app: null
08-27 21:23:21.586: D/ExchangeService(633): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
08-27 21:23:26.696: D/ExchangeService(633): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
08-27 21:23:26.716: W/ActivityManager(286): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
08-27 21:23:26.716: D/ExchangeService(633): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
08-27 21:23:26.737: W/ActivityManager(286): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
08-27 21:23:26.766: E/ActivityThread(633): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d18878 that was originally bound here
08-27 21:23:26.766: E/ActivityThread(633): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d18878 that was originally bound here
08-27 21:23:26.766: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
08-27 21:23:26.766: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
08-27 21:23:26.766: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
08-27 21:23:26.766: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
08-27 21:23:26.766: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
08-27 21:23:26.766: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
08-27 21:23:26.766: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
08-27 21:23:26.766: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
08-27 21:23:26.766: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
08-27 21:23:26.766: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
08-27 21:23:26.766: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
08-27 21:23:26.766: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-27 21:23:26.766: E/ActivityThread(633):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-27 21:23:26.766: E/ActivityThread(633):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-27 21:23:26.766: E/ActivityThread(633):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-27 21:23:26.766: E/ActivityThread(633):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-27 21:23:26.776: E/StrictMode(633): null
08-27 21:23:26.776: E/StrictMode(633): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d18878 that was originally bound here
08-27 21:23:26.776: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
08-27 21:23:26.776: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
08-27 21:23:26.776: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
08-27 21:23:26.776: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
08-27 21:23:26.776: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
08-27 21:23:26.776: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
08-27 21:23:26.776: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
08-27 21:23:26.776: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
08-27 21:23:26.776: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
08-27 21:23:26.776: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
08-27 21:23:26.776: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
08-27 21:23:26.776: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-27 21:23:26.776: E/StrictMode(633):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-27 21:23:26.776: E/StrictMode(633):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-27 21:23:26.776: E/StrictMode(633):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-27 21:23:26.776: E/StrictMode(633):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-27 21:23:26.786: W/ActivityManager(286): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@412162c0
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d18ba8 that was originally bound here
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d18ba8 that was originally bound here
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-27 21:23:26.796: E/ActivityThread(633):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-27 21:23:26.826: E/StrictMode(633): null
08-27 21:23:26.826: E/StrictMode(633): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d18ba8 that was originally bound here
08-27 21:23:26.826: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
08-27 21:23:26.826: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
08-27 21:23:26.826: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
08-27 21:23:26.826: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
08-27 21:23:26.826: E/StrictMode(633):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
08-27 21:23:26.826: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
08-27 21:23:26.826: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
08-27 21:23:26.826: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
08-27 21:23:26.826: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
08-27 21:23:26.826: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
08-27 21:23:26.826: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
08-27 21:23:26.826: E/StrictMode(633):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
```

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("",html, mimeType, encoding, ""), this line is giving error !

Comment: com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1.htmlViewer.onCreate(htmlViewer.java:58)?

Comment: wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("",html, mimeType, encoding, "");
for webview

Comment: pse post htmlviewer.xml

Comment: your code works correctly at my side, seems an error in naming your webView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that your findViewbyId is returning null for the Webview lookup.  This means that it simply isn't finding the resource R.id.webView1.  Make sure your spelling and naming are correct.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to create webview in xml file. Now its working.